# Woocoomerce - вывести описание внизу категории, перекроить вывод доп. инфы в карточке

Tags: woocommerce

Как вывести внизу категории текст-описание? Гугл не помогает... МОжет есть какое-то решение?

Каким образом можно справа от фотографии в карточке товара вывести атрибуты. Т.е. описаний никаких не будет: title, фото и справа атрибуты товаров. Все!

Answer (score 1):

Сам промучал с подобным вопросом.. Прелопатил кучу форумов в поисках нормальных примеров и ответом... НУ как всегда у наших прогеров ЧСВ выше их знаний, не у всех правда, но все же...

Пробовал решить похожий вопрос переопределением вывода данных в разных хуках WC. Толку ноль.

В итоге, там где мне нужно сделал свой хук do_action() и в него потом засунул вывод того элемента страницы, который мне нужен. Вывод делался через function.php - отключался старый хук и элемент, и потом подключался в новый, созданый мною... работает)